# display a map if the table is empty

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, uitableview, swift4

This is the code I tried to display a map when UITable is empty

```
var mapView:GMSMapView?

     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        if orders.count > 0 {
            self.tableview.backgroundView = nil
            self.tableview.separatorStyle = .singleLine
            return 1
        }

        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))


        //so the mapView is of width 200, height 200 and its center is same as center of the self.view
        mapView?.center = self.view.center
       self.tableview.backgroundView = mapView


        return 0
    }
```

But the project crashes and the reason is

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you debug and let me know which line its getting crash ? Start with viewdidload.

Comment: And also shows complete error report in the console log .

Comment: I have imported GoogleMaps and used Google Key in AppDelegate but I still got reason: `'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you were returning `0` no matter what the previous conditions were.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if orders.count > 0 {

        tableview.backgroundView = nil
        tableview.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        return 1

    } else {

        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))
        mapView?.center = view.center
        tableview.backgroundView = mapView
        return 0

    }

}
```

Comment: I have imported GoogleMaps and used Google Key in AppDelegate but I still got `reason: 'Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not initialized APIkey in AppDelegate. Just follow this step.

Import this file in AppDelegate.

```
import GoogleMaps 
import GooglePlaces
```

And than add the api key in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("Your key")
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("Your key")
```

You can get an API Key from the Google Developers Console when you register  App.

For more info please check this link:-  [Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start/%22Developers%20Console%20%22)

Comment: Already did that. I'm using Google map in other ViewController and it works fine. But in this view, I get this error.

Comment: I think because Google Maps code runs before API key is initialized.